# Logstash input Filebeat

Tags: logstash, syslog, logstash-configuration, elastic-stack, filebeat

First of all I apologize for my English.

I'm an intern in a company and I put up a solution ELK with Filebeat to send the logs.

The problem is that once recover syslog_pri always displays Notice and severity_code 5

Here is my configuration :

Logstash input :

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    type => "logs"
    #ssl => true
    #ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    #ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }
}
```

My Filter :

```
filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri {
    syslog_pri_field_name => "syslog_pri"
    }
    geoip {
      source => "ip"
    }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}
```

and I receive the logs like this :

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2016.01.27",
  "_type": "log",
  "_id": "AVKDkbeIo9FUMGLWSx1L",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "2016-01-27T15:52:20.979+0100 WARN  [HeartbeatService RUNNING] collector.heartbeat.HeartbeatService - Unable to send heartbeat to Graylog server: ConnectException: Connection refused",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-01-27T14:52:21.896Z",
    "beat": {
      "hostname": "LABSRVITT003",
      "name": "LABSRVITT003"
    },
    "count": 1,
    "fields": null,
    "input_type": "log",
    "offset": 28494893,
    "source": "/var/log/graylog-collector/collector.log",
    "type": "log",
    "host": "LABSRVITT003",
    "tags": [
      "gpf_relp"
    ],
    "syslog_severity_code": 5,
    "syslog_facility_code": 1,
    "syslog_facility": "user-level",
    "syslog_severity": "notice"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1453906341896
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1453906341896
  ]
}
```

I'm posting this because I am really short of ideas I toured the documentation but I find nothing .

This link :

[https://serverfault.com/questions/735230/why-cant-the-logstash-syslog-pri-filter-see-the-priority-in-syslog-messages]
This person have the same problem and he succeeded.

So if somebody have an idea share it.

Thanks

Comment: I am also having issues similar to this where I can feed files into LogStash via Beats, but its not picking up any of my fields.tags or whatever I put in there per prospector.

Answer (score 0):

I have no syslog_pri experience, but it seems like the other guy had a field `syslog5424_pri` that had the priority value. You gave a field name `syslog_pri` that doesn't even exist in the record. All I see are these:

```
"syslog_severity_code": 5,
"syslog_facility_code": 1,
"syslog_facility": "user-level",
"syslog_severity": "notice"
```

So if you recognize one of these as a priority field then I would suggest changing the syslog_pri plugin config, or if none of these are priority fields, then you first need to create it.
Again, I have no syslog experience, I just looked at your problem and his solution.